# Span element height issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to customize  the file input control. What I did was

```
<div class="ui-select form-input" style="display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:-8px;width:400px;">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-file" for="multiple_input_group">
            <div class="input required">
                <input id="multiple_input_group" type="file" multiple name="files" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)">
            </div> Browse
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="file-input-label" ng-model="fileName"></span>
</div>
```

This

```
<span class="file-input-label" ng-model="fileName"></span>
```

displays the file name upon selection . But it expands height and UI gets out of proportions if file name is large enough Like this

[image]

I tried giving it a width but it did not work .

```
.file-input-label {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height:20px
}
```

How to get it to work ?

Comment: what do you want to happen if the filename is too long?  It would be also if you could supply all the css for that section of html

Comment: I want it not to expand . But to stay as it is . File Name Could just well be padded with dots or something like that.

Comment: have a look at overflow hidden, white-space nowrap and text-overflow ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the height of the container (.file-input-label), you don't need it to be displayed as a table-cell. Set it as block (or inline-block) instead.
To align it verticaly, use paddings (or line-height).

Answer (score 0):

try with the class like this

https://plnkr.co/edit/cx8F3V8m3VfK5k9rJclm?p=preview

in css

```
.file-input-label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

you should use ng-bind for span tag.

read more here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind